# Which of these opposite analysis of Mecanum Wheels is correct?

Tags: forces, rotational-dynamics, friction, free-body-diagram

I was watching the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=83tVkgT89dM

about Mecanum wheels and at 2:41 they display a force diagram which describes the forces the mecanum wheel exerts:

[image: Diagram of Force]

Now I think this diagram is wrong. Because I believe the cause of the mecanum slide is due to friction and therefore the force of friction will act in a direction parallel to the turning of the mecanum rollers. I.E. this is what I believe is the correct force diagram expression

[image: My force diagram]

Notice the x-component of my "blue arrow" points in the opposite direction of the "orange arrow" in the original video, but same y direction.

One of us or neither must be correct, but certainly both of us are not correct.

Which of us (if either) is correct? and if its the video, where do i go wrong with my force diagram?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The video is correct and so is your thinking. What you are missing is that the diagram in the video shows the top of the wheel and not the bottom of the wheel. The roller at the bottom of the wheel is perpendicular to the roller at the top.